# VBA .Execute findText:= multiple options

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a script which is going to look through about 800 documents and add some wording to a specific section.  In most cases that section will have some very specific wording, but it is not always the exact same.

I'd like to create a way for the macro to search for several different possibilities, so far for the actual find and append I have this:

```
Sub newLines()
    With Selection.Find
        .Execute findText:="specific wording"
    End With

    Selection.EndOf unit:=wdCell
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

I'd like to create something that gives the `findText:=` param additional options.

```
.Execute findText:= "specific wording" Or "specific wording 2" Or "specific wording3"
```

That's just pusdo code but if there is something that can give me that type of functionality I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Word simply does not have this facility. There's no alternative when using Word's `Find` functionality - it's necessary to run a separate `Find` for each term to be searched. What could be done to make things more efficient is to limit the part of the document to be searched. For example, if "section" means a Word `Section` (there's a section break) then the search `Range` (rather than `Selection`) could be set specifically to that section and not check the rest of the document.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister, I will try that.  I guess one way to do the `Or` equivalent would be a series of if statements with different Finds in each.

Comment: Yes, that approach would be possible. Another thing to consider would be to put all the terms in an array (or similar construct) that can be looped - the entire `Find` would be in a `For` reducing the number of lines in the code and providing for more flexibility in case the number of things to be searched changes.

Comment: @tfantina If the start & end words are always the same, or the start word is always the same and the string ends at the found paragraph's end, you could use a single *wildcard* Find expression.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples for you.
As Cindy said. Try avoid Selection, but I know that sometimes is impossible.

```
Sub test1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("specific wording 2", "specific wording 3", "specific wording 4")

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Selection.HomeKey wdStory
        Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=arr(i)
        Do While Selection.Find.Found
            'do your stuff
            Selection.Find.Execute
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub



Sub test2()
     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
     Selection.HomeKey wdStory
     Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="specific wording [0-9]"
     Do While Selection.Find.Found
         'do your stuff
         Selection.Find.Execute
     Loop
End Sub
```